# Can I make Windows Explorer to match *any part* of file or folder name when typing (like Total Commander's Quick Search)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

If you have a Windows Explorer window open, and it has the focus, then typing something will select the first file or folder that starts with what was typed. This is useful, but I would like it to behave like e.g. TotalCommander's Quick Search or Quick Filter: it selects the first file/folder that matches *any* part of the filename that matches.

For example, if I have a folder which contains the following files:

```
readme.txt
readyou.txt
readus.txt
```

Then typing `y` or `yo`, should select the file `readyou.txt`. (Currently the only way to select this file is to type at least `ready`)

Is it somehow possible to make Windows Explorer behave like this, either with built-in functionality or using a third-party tool (e.g. a plugin)?

Comment: you say that Total Comander can do this, why not to use it? It seems that this is impossible by default. Only first letter.

Comment: @Ishiwaka: because, among others, that requires me to relearn a whole bunch of keyboard shortcuts and workflows.

Answer (score 1):

I offer this as a work around.

The only way I know (without a third party tool) is to use the asterisk (<kbd>*</kbd>) symbol and treat it in a similarISH way to a WildCard from within the search box.

E.g., if you had a text file on your PC called HolidayList.txt you could search for `*day*` and it would display.

Although I'm not sure how relevant to your question directly, there are some websites which list 'advanced' queries, such as http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2010/03/mastering-windows-search-using-advanced-query-syntax/

Comment: This only works in the Search box. I am not talking about the search box

Comment: @Rabarberski Oh, I'm sorry, so if you have many files listed (eg abc.txt, bcd.txt and cde.txt) and typed the letter B it would jump to the first file in the list with a B (in this case bcd.txt)?

Comment: Yes. But, if you typed `ed` I would want it to (in your example list)  jump to `cde.txt` as this is the first file that *contains* the string `ed`.

Comment: @Rabarberski And you want it to cycle through everything I assume. So, when I press B it will detect bcd.txt. When I press B again, it will then jump to abc.txt (and of course not select cde.txt)?